# HP Pavilion G62 is burning hot

Tags: hp-pavilion

This thing is burning hot my bed nearly caught fire 100 degrees I smell it burning my table. what to do? i don't understand technical stuff is the fan blocked. English second language.

Comment: If you do not understand how to clean the fan, take it to a technician.

Answer (score 1):

keeping the notebok on a less rigid surface, as the bed is, obstructs sometimes the heat exhaust. But since this happens on the table, too, something is not right. You can use Speedfan (http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to read the system temperature, but if I were you, especially since you are not that confident in the hardware domain...I'd get it to a repair shop. Maybe you have a buddy that knows how to deal with it? You may be risking hardware failure, as things are now.